# Unable to open software-properties-gtk on 18.04

Tags: software-center, dbus

When I type `software-properties-gtk` (with `sudo -H` or not) on terminal, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/software-properties-gtk", line 100, in <module>
    app = SoftwarePropertiesGtk(datadir=options.data_dir, options=options, file=file)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/gtk/SoftwarePropertiesGtk.py", line 172, in __init__
    self.backend.Reload();
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/proxies.py", line 70, in __call__
    return self._proxy_method(*args, **keywords)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/proxies.py", line 145, in __call__
    **keywords)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/connection.py", line 651, in call_blocking
    message, timeout)
dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name :1.221 was not provided by any .service files
```

I've found that the problem could be linked to the `idna` package so I've tried reinstalling it, but I still get this error.

And idea?

Thanks

Comment: am getting similar: dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name :1.71 was not provided by any .service files

Comment: Also getting this on the latest 19.10. Did you ever get it fixed?